# Backpropagation algorithm with adaptive learning rate

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, backpropagation

I searched to learn Backpropagation algorithm with adaptive learning rate, and find a lot of resources but it was hard for me to understand, because I'm new in neural network. I know how standard backpropagation algorithm works, very well. Is anybody here to explain me how these two algorithms are different from each other?

Comment: "I want to write a matlab program to train a neural network " - what's stopping you? And what is this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939909/performance-in-backpropagation-algorithm

Answer (score 3):

I think the core difference is the update function, as you could see from [here](http://www.math.upatras.gr/~dgs/papers/reports/tr98-02.pdf)

For classic EBP

```
w(k+1) <- w(k) - a * gradient
```

For adaptive learning:

```
w(k+1) <- w(k) - eta * gradient
```

where:

```
eta = 

    (w(k) - w(k-1)) / (gradient(k) - gradient(k-1))    if eta < etamax
    etamax                                             otherwise
```

So you only need to change the weight update function part.  The above is just a simplified version, for implementation, you would have to adjust eta according to the error(k) and error(k-1).  And there are many ways to do that.

The basic idea of *adaptive* is that

1. if you get a smaller error, you want to try increasing learning rate
2. if you get a larger error, you want to decrease learning rate to that it converges